# Attachement Upload (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, php-7.2

If I want to insert a file, into the product, I get the following error message in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at String.parseJSON [as evalJSON] (prototype.js:720)
    at klass.onFileSuccess (instance.js:359)
    at d.<anonymous> (prototype.js:391)
    at d.<anonymous> (flow.min.js:2)
    at k (flow.min.js:2)
    at d.fire (flow.min.js:2)
    at e.chunkEvent (flow.min.js:2)
    at f.event (flow.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.doneHandler (flow.min.js:2)
```

I use the Aitdownloadablefiles extension for attachments, but I don't think that's because it is the same with other extensions that do the same thing.

*Magento Version 1.9.4.5, PHP 7.2*

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the bug:
File: /app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitdownloadablefiles/Block/AdminhtmlCatalogProductEditTabDownloadableFiles.php
Line 174:
Remove the function call "->addSessionParam()"

The result:

```
    public function getConfigJson()
{
    $this->getUploaderConfig()
        ->setFileParameterName('aitfiles')
        ->setTarget(
            Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')
                ->getUrl('aitdownloadablefiles/file/upload', array('type' => 'aitfiles', '_secure' => true))
        );
    $this->getMiscConfig()
        ->setReplaceBrowseWithRemove(true)
    ;
    return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(parent::getJsonConfig());
}
```